# PhoneGap: Unable to change volume of html5 Audio object in ios

Tags: javascript, ios, html, cordova, phonegap-build

I am using HTML5 Audio object in javascript with phonegap for iOS.
It's working fine in Android but I am not able to change volume of audio.
I am using *phonegap* build to build this app.
My target platforms are android ( equal or greater than 4 ) and ios ( equal or greater than 7).

This is my first app but I am working on this for around one month but I am still not that much good that's why I stuck on the volume issue.

I am using following code:

```
var my_audio = new Audio('test.mp3');
my_audio.play();
my_audio.volume=0.4;
console.log(my_audio.volume); // this still outputs 1
```

As you noticed above that volume did not change.

I am using following links for reference:
I am using this links for documentation: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_volume.asp

Can anybody guide that how to overcome this issue?

Any response will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: there is not enough information on your issue. Please **answer the following questions in your post**. Since this appears to be your first post on this subject. Is this your first hybrid App? What is your target platform and their target versions: Android 4,5,6? iOS 7,8,9?
Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) ? Please do not assume the answer, please read the link.
Once you have answer the question *in the post*, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post.

Comment: Please also point to the documentation you are using.

Comment: Thanks @JesseMonroy650 for your response. I updated question. Please check.

Comment: Which documentation are you using?

Comment: I read documentation from http://docs.build.phonegap.com/ whenever needed.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer on this. Which documentation are you using for the *HTML5 Audio*?

Comment: I am using this links for documentation: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_volume.asp

Answer (score 2):

@Stack Developer,
in review of you comments and after reviewing your reference document, I thought it would be prudent to see if there was support for your task.

I started with [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/) and clicked ["audio elements"](http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio) in the HTML5 section. Under known issues I see:

> - Volume is read-only on iOS.
> - Chrome on Android does not support autoplay as advised by the specification.
> - Chrome on Android does not support changing playbackrate as advised by the specification.

At this time, it appears you cannot change the volume for *HTML Audio* on iOS devices.

Comment: Then what should be solution?
I want to play audio in iOS and want to controll volume.
I know that cordova's media plugin has good features including contolling volume but that plugin doe's not work properly on iOS. that plugin freezes. I searched online and many people found same issue with media plugin on iOS so that's why I chosed HTML5 Audio object.

Can you please suggest solution in that case?

Comment: Okay. I reviewed the bugs for the plugin (Media) and iOS. I see [no significant bugs](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10232?jql=project%20%3D%20CB%20AND%20issuetype%20%3D%20Bug%20AND%20status%20%3D%20Open%20AND%20resolution%20%3D%20Unresolved%20AND%20component%20%3D%20%22Plugin%20Media%22%20AND%20text%20~%20%22ios%22%20ORDER%20BY%20priority%20DESC%2C%20summary%20ASC%2C%20updatedDate%20DESC). I suspect what are seeing is people that don't know what they are doing. True there have been bugs with Phongap and iOS, but no crashes that I can see (at least none as active bugs).

Comment: Here is my [links to bug repositories](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/plugins-core-bugs.md). Here is link to a working demo app that works with [Android and iOS](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/Phonegap-Media-Test) It does not use the Volume option. Best of Luck.

Comment: Thanks for sharing useful information. 
I am streaming mp3 audio files from a remote server using media plugin in iOS. whenever I play remote file then screen freezes for few seconds and become normal when it's ready to play  ( buffered  i think ). I think playing local mp3 or local audio file will not cause any issue but  playing remote mp3 file cause freezing issue. The demo app you provided above does not play file from a remote server. I am facing freezing issue if I play audio file from remote server. What do you say about playing file from a remote server using media plugin in ios?

Comment: @StackDeveloper is you look at the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-media), and my example there is a callback `onSuccess()`. This is intended to make the library asynchronous. As such, you use the callback to deal with network (or system) delays. In my example, I ignore the callback, but I guess in the next version I will use the callback such that the example has more general use. FWIW: Any question beyond the original should be moved to a different forum. I suggest [Google Group of Cordova/Phonegap](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/phonegap).

Comment: I checked it's documentation. I am also familiar with onSuccess() and used it as well but onSuccess call back function does not solve freezing issue in ios.

Comment: [Google Group of Cordova/Phonegap](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/phonegap)