# IOS javascript volume change

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

So i am trying to programmaticly to change the volume of my `audio` element.

On `Desktop` it works completely fine however as soon as i go to `IOS` it starts having some problems

Here is the code i use to change the volume:

```
console.log('volumeValue Before ' + this.podcastVolume.val());
this.podCastElement.volume = this.podcastVolume.val();
console.log('volumeValue after ' + this.podCastElement.volume);
```

Now as I can see I also have some console logs to make sure I get the correct values.

On my `IOS` devices this is what they log:

[image]

So it looks like the volume just stays at `1` and doesn't change.

So my question is what can I do about this?

**EDIT here are my elements:***

```
this.podCastElement = $('#podcast').get(0);
this.podcastPlay = $('#podcastPlay');
this.podcastPause = $('#podcastPause');
this.podcastVolume = $('#podcastVolume');
this.podcastProgress = $('#podcastProgress');
```

**Volume button**

```
   <input type="range" class="form-control-range" id="podcastVolume"
                       (change)="changeVolume()" min="0.0" max="1.0" step="0.1">
```

**Audio Element**

```
    <audio id="podcast" preload="auto">
    <source [src]="fileService+podCast.resourceurl" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: What is your `podCastElement`?

Comment: @Justinas ive updated my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PhoneGap: Unable to change volume of html5 Audio object in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35730579/phonegap-unable-to-change-volume-of-html5-audio-object-in-ios)

Comment: The volume of an audio element is read-only on iOS.